# Eclipse Kepler 4.3 - Error while installing software JBoss Tools

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

In Eclipse Kepler 4.3 I am trying to install JBoss Tools for Kepler 4.3 from [site](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/kepler/4.1.2.Final.html). I am using JBoss Tools 4.1.2 Final. I am getting below multiple errors. Find error details below:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate.ui_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate.ui_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate.xml_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate.xml_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate3_5_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate3_5_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate4_0_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.hibernate4_0_3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.jmx.core_1.4.1.Final-v20140318-1509-B179.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.jmx.core_1.4.1.Final-v20140318-1509-B179.jar
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/features/org.jboss.tools.jmx.feature_1.4.1.Final-v20140318-1509-B179.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.jmx.ui_1.4.1.Final-v20140318-1509-B179.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.jmx.ui_1.4.1.Final-v20140318-1509-B179.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.jsf_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0347-B156.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.jsf_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0347-B156.jar
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/features/org.jboss.tools.jsf.feature_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0347-B156.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.browsersim.win32.win32.x86_64_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.browsersim.win32.win32.x86_64_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.docbook_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.docbook_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/features/org.jboss.tools.vpe.feature_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.html_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.html_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.jsp_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.jsp_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.resref_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.resref_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.spring_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.spring_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.ui.palette_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.ui.palette_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.vpe.xulrunner_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.wtp.runtimes.tomcat_1.0.1.Final-v20140318-1509-B179.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.wtp.runtimes.tomcat_1.0.1.Final-v20140318-1509-B179.jar
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/features/org.jboss.tools.wtp.runtimes.tomcat.feature_1.0.1.Final-v20140318-1509-B179.jar
download.jboss.org
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.xulrunner.initializer_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar.pack.gz
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.jboss.tools.xulrunner.initializer_3.5.1.Final-v20140303-0018-B169.jar
download.jboss.org
Unknown Host: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/static/releases/JBossTools-4.1.2.Final.core/plugins/org.mozilla.xpcom_1.9.2.16.jar
download.jboss.org
```

Next Time when I tried to download again I got the error as:

```
No repository found at http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler/.
```

There is no problem with my internet connection, but I am not sure why such errors are coming while installing software JBoss Tools.
Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Are you able to access (http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler/) from a web browser? It works for me btw.

Comment: Yes. I am able to access the link given above. I tried it 3-4 times, but getting same error.

Comment: Perhaps your Eclipse installation has an obsolete or broken proxy configured? Or maybe it needs one to be configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just faced the same problem, and I'm using a direct connection. Checking the network connections, I've noticed that it was set to "Native" (probably Eclipse Kepler's default, since my installation is rather new).

It was solved by changing Network Connections "Active Provider" from **Native** to **Direct**.

Path to network configuration in Eclipse:
*Windows>>Preferences>>General>>Network Connection*

[image: Eclipse Network Connection Window]

Answer (score 1):

Same problem occurs with Eclipse Luna as well. Setting Active Provider to Direct solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the above answer did not work because we are using a proxy to connect to the internet. So our settings are manual for the network

But I resolved it:

1. Go to `Help` --> `Install New Software`.
2. Add the repository link http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler.
3. Choose `Hibernate Tools` from the options.
4. Accept the licence and proceeding with the installation.
5. Restart Eclipse and Hurray!